# Files can't be saved in collection

Tags: directus

I created a collection which including one "Files" field, the type of the field is Files. When I uploaded the files and save the element, I got one error saying:

> error msg: api[_].ERROR:
>   Zend\Db\Sql\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Argument type should
>   be in array(identifier,value) in 
>   /directus/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/Sql/AbstractExpression.php:82

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide the version you're running?

An error like this was fixed in the most recent update of Directus, please ensure you've updated *(git pull origin)* to have this fix.

Comment: The version is 7.6.0. I did a git pull origin just now, but the error still exists.